# Class import error in Scala/Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to Spark and I'm using it with Scala. I wrote a simple `object` that is loaded fine in `spark-shell` using `:load test.scala`.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexer

object Collaborative{
    def trainModel() ={
        val data = sc.textFile("/user/PT/data/newfav.csv")
        val df = data.map(_.split(",") match {
            case Array(user,food,fav) => (user,food,fav.toDouble)
        }).toDF("userID","foodID","favorite")
        val userIndexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("userID").setOutputCol("userIndex")
    }
}
```

Now I want to put it in a class to pass parameters. I use the same code with `class` instead.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexer

class Collaborative{
    def trainModel() ={
        val data = sc.textFile("/user/PT/data/newfav.csv")
        val df = data.map(_.split(",") match {
            case Array(user,food,fav) => (user,food,fav.toDouble)
        }).toDF("userID","foodID","favorite")
        val userIndexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("userID").setOutputCol("userIndex")
    }
}
```

This returns import errors.

```
<console>:19: error: value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String, Double)]
           val df = data.map(_.split(",") match { case Array(user,food,fav) => (user,food,fav.toDouble) }).toDF("userID","foodID","favorite")

<console>:24: error: not found: type StringIndexer
           val userIndexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("userID").setOutputCol("userIndex")
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, this one seems to work fine.

```
def trainModel() ={
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("test").master("local").getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._ 
    val data = spark.read.textFile("/user/PT/data/newfav.csv")
    val df = data.map(_.split(",") match {
      case Array(user,food,fav) => (user,food,fav.toDouble)
    }).toDF("userID","foodID","favorite")
    val userIndexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("userID").setOutputCol("userIndex")
  }
```